# How to import Observer with ForkJoin in RXJS 6.3.3?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I tried:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

It says: module Observable has no imported, also does not work `map` for `fork`:

```
return Observable.forkJoin([
      this.loadCompanies(),
      this.loadUsers(),
      this.loadEvents()
    ]).map((data: any[]) => {});
```

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forkJoin` is a stand-alone factory function and imported as `import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';`

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: I tried `import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';` it does not support map for fork

Comment: again, `map` is a standalone factory function which must piped, i.e., `forkJoin().pipe(map(...));`

Comment: So, to use map I must import also: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`?

Comment: Yes. You must import all of the pipeable operators that were on the prototype in rxjs 5.